# Why does my iOS widget only show placeholder data instead of fetched data when using an async function in getTimeline()

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widgetkit

I'm making a widget for my iOS App, and having some problems in using it.

I have an async function which fetches data from the server in the `getTimeline()` method of the `Provider`. However, whenever I run my widget target, it only shows the placeholder data, and not any of the data fetched (if it was).
An interesting find is, whenever I straight up return the completion from my data fetch function without any delay, the widget works fine.

I want to understand what could be the problem here.

My Data fetcher function:

```swift
func fetchData(completion: @escaping (Date?) -> Void) async {
    let result = await self.fetch()
    completion(result)
}
```

Get Timelines function:

```swift
func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
    Task {
       await DataFetcher().fetchData { data in
           // make timelines
           let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
           completion(timeline)
       }
    }
}
```

My guess is that the data fetcher function is timing out and the widget is deallocating resources before it could run, because the instant completion handler works fine.

Would love some help and insight on this.

Answer (score 0):

Your `fetchData` function is incorrect. You're trying to mix async with a completion handler, and it's returning out of order. Looking at your code, there's no reason for `fetchData` to exist. It's just `fetch`:

```
func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
    Task {
        // Here, just call fetch. This is already an async context.
        let data = await DataFetcher().fetch()

        // make timelines
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
    }
}
```

That said, from your description, it is also possible that you have errors in `fetch`. It's very surprising that it doesn't `throw`. How do you handle failures? I would double-check that you don't have an error that you're ignoring (with `try?` or the like, for example).